# Invalid Value for Parameter 'recovery_target_time' in Postgres Database

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-14

Wishing you all a Happy and Prosperous New Year!

I am getting below error while restoring postgres database to a specific target time (PITR):

```
Invalid value for parameter recovery_target_time in file postgresql.conf
```

And database is not getting restored. I have tried following values for `recovery_target_time`:

```
recovery_target_time = '2022-12-31 12:45:00 UTC'
recovery_target_time = '2022-12-31 12:45:00 UTC+00'
recovery_target_time = '2022-12-31 12:45:00 UTC+00:00'
recovery_target_time = '2022-12-31 12:45:00 Etc/UTC'
recovery_target_time = '2022-12-31 12:45:00.000'
```

But none of the above is working.
What value should be used for `recovery_target_time`?.
I am using postgresql 14 on Ubuntu 22.04 and trying restore database using `pg_basebackup`. Timezone is in UTC. Let me know if I need to add more details.

Update: Provided logs

```
2022-12-30 13:32:19.686 UTC [34563] LOG: invalid value for parameter &quot;recovery_target_time&quot;: &quot;2022–12–30 12:45:00 UTC+00:00&quot;
```

Comment: It should be `recovery_target_time = '2022-12-31 12:45:00 UTC'`, not `recovery_target_time " '2022-12-31 12:45:00 UTC'`.

Comment: Thanks Laurenz for the response. Using '=' sign only. I miss typed here. I have updated my query.

Comment: Can you share your basebackup command ?

Comment: Thanks  sami for the response. I think basebackup command is okay. Because am able to create other servers(standby)using basebackup. Restoration is okay without recovery_target_time parameter.

Comment: Please edit the question and add the lines from the PostgreSQL log that stem from the attempted recovery.

Comment: I don't see anywhere in the source code which generate that error message exactly as quoted.  Did you paraphrase that?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe       added logs to query. Please check if this can help us to troubleshoot the issue. Thanks.

Comment: That `&quot;` looks fishy. Are you sure it was like that in the log file?

Comment: Issue resolved after using following parameter: recovery_target_time = '2022-12-31 12:45:00+00'